Возврат переменной в КУМИРЕ
Можно ли возвращать переменные в кумире? Нужно сделать так что бы функция check_numbers возвращала значение x в основной алгоритм, который передаёт это значение в другую функцию.
алг Факториал положительных чисел
нач
цел n1,n2,x
вывод "Введите n1 "
ввод n1
вывод "Введите n2 "
ввод n2
check_numbers(n1,n2)
x:= check_numbers(n1,n2)
Fact(n2,x)
кон


алг check_numbers(цел n1,цел n2)
нач
цел x
x:=n1
нц пока x<0
вывод нс, x , " - Не положительное "
x:=x+1
кц

кон

алг Fact (цел x,цел n2)
нач
цел i,F
F:= 1
если x = 0 
то вывод "Присутствует 0. Факториал равен 1"
иначе
нц для i от x до n2
F:=F*i
вывод нс,"Факториал равен "
кц
всё
кон


сомнительно что тут вам кто то ответит, с учетом того что это учебный язык. Но при беглом просмотре документации - вроде как да - посмотрите "Алгоритмы с результатами" по ссылке - https://foxford.ru/wiki/informatika/algoritmy-protsedury-i-algoritmy-funktsii-v-kumir

У функции указывается тип, а результат присваивается специальной переменной знач (почитать)
алг цел check_numbers(цел n1,цел n2)
  ...
  x := x+1
  знач := x
кц

